# Flutter build appbundle

Tags: flutter, android-app-signing

So I have generated my app keys for upload and when I try to build app bundle I get the error in the below image.

[Flutter Error When Building App Bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84dFY.png)

I have setup my Build.gradle and my key.properties files as well

I also tried appending the --stacktrace to the build command and I received the below.

[flutter build appbundle --stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYAHp.png)

Comment: Try signing with a new key

Comment: Ok will try now

Comment: Do you know how I can get the images to show as the full images and not a link?

Comment: @PrinceSanjivy I tried a new key but got the same issue

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post check this to post image directly instead of url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem then I realized that it's pretty simple to create appbundle by opening the android folder of the flutter app in android studio. please ignore any settings of Keystore on flutter side and follow these steps:

1. Open android studio
2. go to file > open > select android folder from the flutter project
3. wait until the Gradle build is finished
4. from topbar goto build > generate signed bundle/apk > select appbundle
5. Fill in the Keystore info(+android studio will remember it for you)
6. hit release and wait until it's finished

Note: make sure to change the version and build number if you're pushing an update.

Comment: Will this approach also handle obfuscating the Dart code?

Comment: You don't have to change anything in the dart code and do this process each time you make an app bundle.

Comment: There is no signed button, just Build App Bundle